# django and html output

Tags: python, html, django

this program takes the input and displays it with the time (using python and HTML)
I have a problem with the output below

[image: 1]

here with adding out.**stdout** to take the output only ..

[image: 2]

but the output have a  (**b'**)

[image: 3]

**how can I display the output without this 'b and the \r\n'?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the std.out to string ,I things its being encoded in bytes

Comment: thank you so much I added this
   return render(request,'home.html',{'data1': str(out.stdout , 'utf-8')})
and it works